# Headers with chapter titles only

Tags: memoir

I am using memoir and there is a problem with the headers.
I see section titles in the headers but I only want to see chapter titles regardless of section titles in the chapter.
My tex file is included below. What I want is to have "Short chapter title" appear in the header of all pages in Chapter 1, but instead I get section and subsection titles from file chapter1.tex. How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}

\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

\chapter[Short chapter title]{Long chapter title}
\input{chapter1.tex}

\bibliography{b} 
\bibliographystyle{acm} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you talking about headings or headers? Because that is a significant difference.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memoir` provides some fairly convenient commands for setting these.  Firsly, you can remove the sections in the headers via

```
\clearmark{section}
```

Secondly, the command `\createmark{chapter}...` will set headings changing at each chapter.  To get the standard style of chapter heading on each page write

```
\makeatletter
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\makeatother
```

The `\makeatletter / \makeatother` combination is required as one of the commands contains the `@` sign.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\OnehalfSpacing

\clearmark{section}
\makeatletter
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter[Short chapter title]{Long chapter title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A section}
\label{sec:section}

\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using memoir 2009/09/21 v1.61803398b and I get                 ! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \clearmark
               {section}

Comment: Then update, you are way way behind. Sounds like some older Linux?

Comment: How do I move the page number to the middle of the footer? I tried using \pagestyle{ruled} but it messed up the header.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using ruled page style, with page numbers in the footers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\OnehalfSpacing

\makeevenhead{ruled}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{}{}{\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\chapter[Short chapter title]{Long chapter title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A section}
\label{sec:section}

\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```